# How do I combine multiple char reads into a std::vector?

Tags: c++

I'm reading multiple reports from a HID device into an `unsigned char`, then trying to copy the data to a `std::vector`.  I'm also writing the data out to a file for hex analysis, whose content appears to be correct when I view it.  However, the `std::vector` doesn't appear to contain the correct data when I dump it to the console.

This is the code:

```
typedef vector<unsigned char> buffer_t;

buffer_t sendCommand (hid_device *devh, const unsigned char cmd[], int reports) {
    unsigned char outbuf[0x40];
    buffer_t retbuf(0x40 * reports);

    hid_write(devh, cmd, 0x41);

    int i;
    FILE *file = fopen("test.out", "w+b");
    while (i++ < reports) {
       hid_read(devh, outbuf, 0x40);
       fwrite(outbuf, 1, sizeof(outbuf), file);
       retbuf.push_back(*outbuf);
    }
    fclose(file);
    cout << &retbuf[0];
    return retbuf;
}
```

I have a feeling I'm way off the mark here; I'm fairly new to C/C++, and I've been stuck with this for a while now.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or point me in a better direction?

Comment: Your vector will contain only first character of outbuf, as you are using *outbuf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to add multiple `unsigned char` objects to your vector, but `push_back` only adds one.

So, replace `retbuf.push_back(*outbuf);` with either:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(outbuf); ++i) {
    retbuf.push_back(outbuf[i]);
}
```

or

```
std::copy(outbuf, outbuf+sizeof(outbuf), std::back_inserter(retbuf));
```

or

```
retbuf.insert(retbuf.end(), outbuf, outbuf+sizeof(outbuf));
```

which all do the same thing.

You create your vector with a certain size:

```
buffer_t retbuf(0x40 * reports);
```

but `push_back` increases the size of the vector by adding an element at the end. You should create it empty:

```
buffer_t retbuf;
```

Optionally, you could arrange for the vector to have enough space allocated, ready for the elements you're going to add:

```
retbuf.reserve(0x40 * reports);
```

This is purely a performance issue, but sometimes it's a significant issue for large vectors, or vectors of types that (unlike `unsigned char`) are expensive to copy/move when the vector runs out of internal space and has to allocate more.

A note on style: you repeat the literal value `0x40` a few times, and also use `sizeof(outbuf)`. It's often best to define a constant, and use the name throughout:

```
const int report_size = 0x40;
```

This is partly in case the number changes in future, but also it's about the readability of your code -- if someone sees `0x40` they may or may not immediately understand why that is the correct value. If someone sees `report_size` then they don't know what value that actually is until they look it up, but they do know why you're using that value.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I've tried each one of your solutions, you're right that they all do the same thing.  However, the output to the console still isn't correct when I use `cout << &rebuf[0]` (`sizeof()` is 8, not 0x40*reports). Could this have something to do with how the HID reports are structured? They write to the file just fine...

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, that's what I'm seeing. I thought it would dump the whole thing, but I see now why it wouldn't... how would I dump the whole thing?  I was planning on copying the memory over a struct so that I could just grab the parts I needed from the report.

Comment: `&retbuf[0]` is a pointer to the first `unsigned char` in the vector. It has type `unsigned char*`, and when you `cout<<` it, the address is printed. Sorry about my previous comment that I deleted -- it was wrong because I missed the `&`. To dump the whole vector do either `std::copy(retval.begin(), retval.end(), ostream_iterator<unsigned char>(cout));` or else `std::copy(retval.begin(), retval.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));`, according to whether the data is human readable (so print it as chars) or binary (so print it as numbers).

Comment: Oh, and if you're planning to copy the memory over a struct, then it might be better to have a `vector<my_report_struct>` in the first place rather than a `vector<unsigned char>`.

Comment: Oops, another error on my part -- `operator<<(const unsigned char*)` doesn't print the address, it behaves like the `char*` overload, and expects a nul-terminated C-style string. So it might print part of the data in the vector and then stop, or if there's no terminating byte in the vector then it might print the whole contents of the vector and then overrun, resulting in undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep playing around with it and see what I can do. It's all part of the learning process, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line: `buffer_t retbuf(0x40 * reports);` It means that you create vector with `0x40 * reports` elements filled with default value for unsigned char (zero). Then `push_back()` just adds new elements to the end of vector and doesn't affect existing elements.

You need to rewrite it this way:

```
buffer_t retbuf;                  // Empty vector
retbuf.reserve(0x40 * reports);   // Preallocate memory for known element count
```

This way `push_back()` will work as expected and add elements to empty vector from beginning.

And of course you shall push_back() all elements of `outbuf`, not only first one (`*outbuf`).

Answer (score 1):

To push back multiple values use std::vector's function assign. For example:

```
std::vector<char>vec1;
char array[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
vec1.assign(array, array+3);
```

I am currently working on a project were I had to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your vector is of a type `unsigned char`, which means every element of it is of this type. Your `outbuf` is an *array* of unsigned chars.

The `push_back()` only appends one item to the end of the vector, so `push_back(*outbuf)` will only add the first element of the `outbuf` to the vector, not all of them.

To put all the data into the vector, you will need to `push_back` them one-by-one, or use `std::copy`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that since outbuf is a char array, then *outbuf will be the first element of the char array because of the array/pointer duality.

I think you probably wanted to do:

```
typedef vector<string> buffer_t; // alternatively vector<unsigned char*>
...
retbuf.push_back(outbuf);
...
```

Or

```
typedef vector<unsigned char> buffer_t;
...
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(outbuf); i++)
     retbuf.push_back(outbuf);
...
```